# Сохранение сессии Telegram API

Tags: java, telegram

Приветствую.

Возник вопрос по поводу Telegram API (не Bot API). Не могу понять, как сохранить данные пользователя после его первой аутентификации в приложении. В данный момент при каждом входе идет запрос кода.

После первого удачного входа пробовал сохранять `phoneCodeHash`, номер телефона и `phoneCode`. В принципе, это работает до истечения срока кода аутентификации.

Возможно, сейчас я путаю, потому что использую представление данного API на Java с библиотекой [Kotlogram](https://github.com/badoualy/kotlogram). Реализация аутентификации в сэмпле:

ApiStorage.java

```
public static class ApiStorage implements TelegramApiStorage {

//Create File variable for auth.key and dc.save
public static final File AUTH_KEY_FILE = new File("Properties/auth.key");
public static final File NEAREST_DC_FILE = new File("Properties/dc.save");

@Override
public void saveAuthKey(@NotNull AuthKey authKey) {
    try {
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(AUTH_KEY_FILE, authKey.getKey());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public AuthKey loadAuthKey() {
    try {
        return new AuthKey(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(AUTH_KEY_FILE));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!(e instanceof FileNotFoundException))
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void saveDc(@NotNull DataCenter dataCenter) {
    try {
        FileUtils.write(NEAREST_DC_FILE, dataCenter.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public DataCenter loadDc() {
    try {
        String[] infos = FileUtils.readFileToString(NEAREST_DC_FILE).split(":");
        return new DataCenter(infos[0], Integer.parseInt(infos[1]));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!(e instanceof FileNotFoundException))
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void deleteAuthKey() {
    try {
        FileUtils.forceDelete(AUTH_KEY_FILE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void deleteDc() {
    try {
        FileUtils.forceDelete(NEAREST_DC_FILE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void saveSession(@Nullable MTSession session) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public MTSession loadSession() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Сама аутентификация в Java Console.

```
public class Main {
// Get them from Telegram's console
public static final int API_ID = api id;
public static final String API_HASH = api hash;

// What you want to appear in the "all sessions" screen
public static final String APP_VERSION = "AppVersion";
public static final String MODEL = "Model";
public static final String SYSTEM_VERSION = "SysVer";
public static final String LANG_CODE = "en";

public static TelegramApp application = new TelegramApp(API_ID, API_HASH, MODEL, SYSTEM_VERSION, APP_VERSION, LANG_CODE);
public static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "тут был телефон"; // International format

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TelegramClient client = Kotlogram.getDefaultClient(application, new ApiStorage());

    try {
        TLSentCode sentCode = client.authSendCode(false, PHONE_NUMBER, true);
        System.out.println("Authentication code: ");
        String code = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        TLAuthorization authorization = client.authSignIn(PHONE_NUMBER, sentCode.getPhoneCodeHash(), code);
        TLUser self = authorization.getUser().getAsUser();
        System.out.println("You are now signed in as " + self.getFirstName() + " " + self.getLastName() + " @" + self.getUsername());
    } catch (RpcErrorException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        client.close(); // Important, do not forget this, or your process won't finish
    }
}
}
```

Данную реализацию я использую в Android приложении. Конечно, все раскидано по асинхронным потокам. Но каждый раз при входе в приложение идет проверка кода авторизации. Из-за этого я за сегодня заблокировал 3 разных аккаунта на день по причине флуда авторизации.

В качестве обходного варианта я использовал подстановку значений в данном методе, запоминая их при удачной авторизации.

```
client.authSignIn(phoneNumber, phoneCodeHash, phoneCode);
```

Это работает только до того момента, пока код не истечет.
Возможно, кто-то знает как это решается на уровне самого API, а не библиотеки, или сможет предложить вариант использования других подходов для работы с Telegram API: стандартный API, TDlib или какое-либо другое решение для авторизации пользователей в приложении через Telegram на Java.

Честно, не смог ни с чем другим разобраться. 
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Я сейчас тоже пишу на java код связанный с библеотекой kotlogram и встал с регистрацией может кто не будь поможет? Вот пример кода Пример кода: TelegramApp app = new TelegramApp(apiId, apiHash, "Mod", "SysVer", "1", "en"); ApiStorage state = new ApiStorage(); TelegramClient client = Kotlogram.getDefaultClient(application, state); в самой последней строчке программа выдает ошибку java.lang.RuntimeException: AuthKey must be 256 Bytes found 0 bytes. В корневом каталоге я создал два файла auth.key и dc.save. Эти файлы у меня пустые а программа ругается что в файле auth.key должно быть что то. Кто-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение методом научного тыка. Я был действительно не прав, т.к. данная библиотека сама умеет отрабатывать сессии. Просто делает это (на мой взгляд) очень неочевидно. Прикладываю ниже рабочее решение в виде консольного приложения на Java. Это же решение работает и для Android приложения.

```
public class Main {
    // Get them from Telegram's console
    private static final int API_ID = /*put api id here*/;
    private static final String API_HASH = "put hash here";

    // What you want to appear in the "all sessions" screen
    private static final String APP_VERSION = "AppVersion";
    private static final String MODEL = "Model";
    private static final String SYSTEM_VERSION = "SysVer";
    private static final String LANG_CODE = "en";

    private static TelegramApp application = new TelegramApp(API_ID, API_HASH, MODEL, SYSTEM_VERSION, APP_VERSION, LANG_CODE);
    private static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "put a phone number here"; // International format

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelegramClient client = Kotlogram.getDefaultClient(application, new ApiStorage());

        try {
            TLUserFull userFull = client.usersGetFullUser(new TLInputUserSelf());
            TLUser self = userFull.getUser().getAsUser();
            showUserInfo(self);
        } catch (RpcErrorException e) {
            if (e.getTag().equals("AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED"))
                signInUser(client);
            else
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }

    private static void signInUser(TelegramClient client) {
        try {
            // Send code to account
            TLSentCode sentCode = client.authSendCode(false, PHONE_NUMBER, true);
            System.out.println("Authentication code: ");
            String code = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

            TLAuthorization authorization = client.authSignIn(PHONE_NUMBER, sentCode.getPhoneCodeHash(), code);
            TLUser self = authorization.getUser().getAsUser();

            showUserInfo(self);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void showUserInfo(TLUser user) {
        System.out.println("You are now signed in as " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + " @" + user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Не знаю, кто плюсовал данный вопрос, но, надеюсь, что оно кому-нибудь поможет.
Спасибо.

Comment: Всего пара-тройка забаненных аккаунтов и я нашёл это сообщение, ура))