# Подключить kotlogram maven java

Tags: java, maven, telegram

Не получается подключить библиотеку kotlogram для использования telegram client api. Пробовал так, не находит библиотеку..

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.majidasgari.kotlogram</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

И так пробовал:

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.badoualy</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlogram</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-RC3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Видимо, у меня проблемы с пониманием, как подключить через maven репозитории github. Кто поправит, буду признателен

P.s. делаю это для того, чтобы протестировать данный пример [Сохранение сессии Telegram API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796761/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-telegram-api)

Answer (score 0):

На https://jitpack.io можно просмотреть все существующие репозитории. В твоем случае вставь ссылку на репозиторий kotlogram в GitHub (https://github.com/badoualy/kotlogram), нажми Look up и выбери нужную версию